# Android Unit Test problem : No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, androidx-test

I followed Android Developer [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests#include-framework-dependencies) and try to make a simple unit test in a Android Project.

But I try to run the unit test with `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()`
than I got a exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.

It seen like I do not registered instrumentation. but the doc dose not mention any thing about this.

It works normal if I do implement Robolectric Library and use `@RunWith(Robolectrictestrunner::class.java)`(and also I need to endure long time setting at first run.). But it's pretty strange because the doc says include the Robolectric environment in androidx.test:core

I want to know did missing something to setting or other right way to unit test with something like SparseArray or the other thing belong Android SDK.

Here is my build.gradle：

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication2"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    // Optional -- Robolectric environment
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.1'

    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Is your test in `test` or `androidTest` directory?

Comment: in the directory ```test```

Comment: Have you got any solution ? Please help, As i am getting the same problem